# How we can pass file content

Tags: java, javascript

I have to select an Image file from my Application and attach it to default mail box(Outlook).
For this I am using Javascript.  I put my Javascript in Ajax on clicking attach to outlook mail, a Java method call and it will convert selected Image to BufferImage.  Can you please tell me how can I pass this to the to my Javascript which I put inside Ajax?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: I converted a Image in 64base image                                       @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
// Decode encoded string into original byte array
        
        
        System.out.println("in try ");
        System.out.println("imagestring "+ imageString);
byte[] decoded = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
        System.out.println("image"+ decoded);BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));

Comment: now I want to pass this image inside my java script

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
     outlookApp=new XMLHttpRequest("Outlook.Application");
      }
    var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
    var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
    mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);
    mailItem = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Note.FormA');
                               mailItem.Attachments.Add ();//here I have to pass that image //
                                mailItem.display (0);                               
 please help me

Comment: Extend your question post with that code snippets.

Comment: I have to attach a attachment to default mail box (outlook)

Comment: I have to attach a attachment to default mail box (outlook).
I am using java script for that I have to select a Image from my application which is already store in my application,for this I have to convert that image in BASE64 image so that I can attach that Image in original form,
problem what I am facing is how Can I pass that Image in java Script 
If know any json object which can store Image tell me

Comment: This is java code I write to convert that image
 @SuppressWarnings("restriction") BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder(); // Decode encoded string into original byte array System.out.println("in try "); System.out.println("imagestring "+ imageString); byte[] decoded = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString); System.out.println("image"+ decoded);BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));

Comment: and this is Java script I use to attach Image in outlook


 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { outlookApp=new XMLHttpRequest("Outlook.Application"); } var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application"); var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI"); mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6); mailItem = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Note.FormA'); mailItem.Attachments.Add ();//here I have to pass that image // mailItem.display (0);

Comment: `mailItem.Attachments.Add ()` method supposed to take the file path in your local system .. like `mailItem.Attachments.Add ("path/to/file")` .. does [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1003014) link help?

Comment: mailItem.Attachments.Add ("path/to/file") yes Its takes like but in my application I have to select a image which is already store ,when I select that Image It will come in string form ,so I converted that string to base 64 image ,now I have to pass this Image in the mailItem.Attachments.Add (); method so  I can store this Image in side any json object ,but I am unable to find any json object which take insted of image path 
If I can find any json object who store image or any thing else sothat I can pass that bse64 image to Java script Metod

please help me

Comment: **Update your question post with code snippets, please!**